# sphinx index with many-to-many relation

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I am trying to set up a Sphinx index with a basic many-to-many relation between artworks and genres:

```
artworks
---------------
id
title
description

genres
---------------
id
name

artwork_genres
---------------
artworks_id
genres_id
```

In my sphinx config file I have something like

```
source src_artwork {
    ...
    sql_query    = SELECT id, title, description FROM artworks
    sql_attr_multi = uint tag from query; SELECT id,name FROM genres
}
```

This is from the docs, as far as I can understand, on [multi-valued attributes](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/mva.html) and [sql_attr_multi](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/conf-sql-attr-multi.html)

But obviously there is no mention of the tie table in there and I can't understand how that is brought into the config. I'd simply like for a search on "Impressionism" to result in artworks belonging to that genre (weighted as appropriate if the term is seen in the other fields)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would consider ignoring the attributes feature in this case. The simplest way to create a genre field by which to search artworks is to "de-normalise" the genres table into the sql_query.

In the FROM clause of your SQL query, you would JOIN the genres table to the artworks via the linking table. In the SELECT clause, you can then GROUP_CONCAT genres.name into a column, which becomes a Sphinx field to search on.

Your sql_query might look like this:

```
source src_artwork {
        ...
    sql_query    = SELECT a.id, a.title, a.description, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT g.name SEPARATOR ' ') AS genre \
        FROM artworks AS a \
        LEFT JOIN artwork_genres AS ag ON ag.artworks_id = a.id \ 
        LEFT JOIN genres AS g ON g.id = ag.genres_id
        GROUP BY a.id;
}
```

Then a sphinx search for artworks looking for "impressionism" in the @genre field will return the "row".

Comment: had to add a `GROUP BY id` at the end of the SQL statement, and it worked! I'd heard of `GROUP_CONCAT` but I didn't put it together that it could make lists of relations like this - kind of a old problem in SQL. Huge lifesaver in this case. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yes - good point. I've edited the answer to reflect your comment. Glad you got it working!